# Application directory path

Tags: php, codeigniter, constants

How can I get the `application` directory path in CodeIgniter? 
Is there any 'not dirty' way to do that?

I was looking through the constants but the most closer one I found was the `BASEPATH` which returns a full path to the `/system` directory, so basicly I can `str_replace` system with the application - but I'm just curious, is there any other clean and short way to get application directory path?

Comment: IIRC, there's the APPPATH constant

Answer (score 5, accepted):

its in your index.php file ( this was taken from CI 2.1 , and its called APPPATH )

```
    // The path to the "application" folder
if (is_dir($application_folder))
{
    define('APPPATH', $application_folder.'/');
}
else
{
    if ( ! is_dir(BASEPATH.$application_folder.'/'))
    {
        exit("Your application folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: ".SELF);
    }

    define('APPPATH', BASEPATH.$application_folder.'/');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can accomplish this with the APPPATH variable.

So to get to your controllers folder it'd be something like.

```
include(APPPATH . 'controllers/')
```

Or whatever you wanted to do with it. Note the trailing slash is included in the APPPATH variable.

Comment: `APPPATH` does return simply `application/` and nothing more - I need a full path to write files in the cache.